# Google sheets export to txt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I made this script to export the data from a column to a .txt on my google drive

```html
function createOrAppendFile() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G50');
  var rows = range.getValues();
  var fileName="test.txt";
  var folderName="Videos";
  var data = rows.splice(0);
  var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("\n");
 
  var content = str;

  // get list of folders with matching name
  var folderList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);  
  if (folderList.hasNext()) {
    // found matching folder
    var folder = folderList.next();

    // search for files with matching name
    var fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

    if (fileList.hasNext()) {
      // found matching file - append text
      var file = fileList.next();
      var combinedContent = content;
      file.setContent(combinedContent);
    }
    else {
      // file not found - create new
      folder.createFile(fileName, content);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I export the data its exporting with the empty lines and on the .txt shows up empty lines that i dont want to have, how i can make it? So I only export the lines that have content.

This is what the .txt looks like  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wplZL.png

Comment: Now I noticed that you had posted the comment as an answer. I apologize for this. From `the modified script works fine`, I could understand your issue was resolved. I'm glad for it. But when you want to comment, please post it to the comment of answer and question. Please don't post it as an answer. Please be careful this. About your new question of `but now i want to know how i can add a "=" before they make the jump to other line like this.`, I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question.

Comment: ok thanks, its my first time using strackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I would like to check it.

Comment: This is the new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841365/put-a-before-text-jump y try my best to explain what i want to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue might be due to `sheet.getRange('G3:G50')`. In this case, even when the empty rows are included below the data range in the range of `G3:G50`, `range.getValues()` retrieves all rows of `G3:G50`. If you want to retrieve the values with the data range, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G50');
```

#### To:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G' + sheet.getLastRow());
```

And, when you want to remove all empty rows of the column "G", you can also use the following modification.

#### From:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G50');
var rows = range.getValues();
```

#### To:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G' + sheet.getLastRow());
var values = range.getValues().filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "");
```

#### References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)