# Put a = before text jump

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello I made this script to export the data from a column to a .txt on my google drive

```html
function maquinasBonusHunt() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var rows = range.getValues().filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "");
  var fileName="maquinas.txt";
  var folderName="Videos";
  var data = rows.splice(0);
  var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("\n");
  var separador = [" - ", " = "];
  var content = str;

  // get list of folders with matching name
  var folderList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);  
  if (folderList.hasNext()) {
    // found matching folder
    var folder = folderList.next();

    // search for files with matching name
    var fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

    if (fileList.hasNext()) {
      // found matching file - append text
      var file = fileList.next();
      var combinedContent = content;
      file.setContent(combinedContent);
    }
    else {
      // file not found - create new
      folder.createFile(fileName, content);
    }
  }
}
```

Everything is fine but, I need to put a "=" before they jump to other text like y show you on the screenshot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvXDA.png

Comment: I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. By the way, what is `-` of `var separador = [" - ", " = "]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add `=` to the last character of each row.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following modification.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `=` is added when `join` is run.

#### From:

```
var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("\n");
```

#### To:

```
var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("=\n") + "=";
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `=` is added after `filter` was used.

#### From:

```
var rows = range.getValues().filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "");
```

#### To:

```
var rows = range.getValues().filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "").map(([v]) => [v + "="]);
```

### References:

- [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hello, I use the first pattern and It works fine, the var separador = [" - ", " = "] was a try that i was making, now, i want to put the content of other row on the txt, i can put another question if you want?

Comment: @Miguel Thank you for replying and providing more information. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I noticed about https://stackoverflow.com/q/64850214/7108653 . So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.