# Add another row content to the .txt

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just got to work the script to export the content of a row to a .txt and put a =, but now i would like to know how i can add the content of other row to the .txt like i will show on the screenshot.
[image: 1]

This is the code that i currently have but i dont properly make to work.

```html
function exporttotxt() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var rows = range.getValues().filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "");
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('I3:I' + sheet.getLastRow());
  var rows2 = range2.getValues().filter(([i]) => i.toString() != "");
  var fileName="exported.txt";
  var folderName="Videos";
  var data = rows.splice(0);
  var data2 = rows2.splice(0);
  var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("=") + "=" + data2.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("\n");
  var content = str;

  // get list of folders with matching name
  var folderList = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);  
  if (folderList.hasNext()) {
    // found matching folder
    var folder = folderList.next();

    // search for files with matching name
    var fileList = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

    if (fileList.hasNext()) {
      // found matching file - append text
      var file = fileList.next();
      var combinedContent = content;
      file.setContent(combinedContent);
    }
    else {
      // file not found - create new
      folder.createFile(fileName, content);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you need to do this `filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "")` since your using getLastRow() in your range.

Comment: What's this for `data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("=")`  e is just an array with only one element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to create a text by merging the values of colums "G" and "I".

In your situation, how about retrieving the values from the columns "G" and "I" by one `getValues`? By this, the process cost will be lower and the script becomes a bit simple. When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('G3:G' + sheet.getLastRow());
var rows = range.getValues().filter(([g]) => g.toString() != "");
var range2 = sheet.getRange('I3:I' + sheet.getLastRow());
var rows2 = range2.getValues().filter(([i]) => i.toString() != "");
var fileName="exported.txt";
var folderName="Videos";
var data = rows.splice(0);
var data2 = rows2.splice(0);
var str = data.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("=") + "=" + data2.map(function(e) {return e.join()}).join("\n");
var content = str;
```

#### To:

```
var range = sheet.getRange('G3:I' + sheet.getLastRow());
var rows = range.getValues().filter(([g, _, i]) => g.toString() != "" && i.toString() != "");
var fileName="exported.txt";
var folderName="Videos";
var data = rows.splice(0);
var str = data.map(([g, _, i]) => `${g}=${i}`).join("\n");
var content = str;
```

Comment: Thanks its working, but how i can change the cell instead of the H cell the I cell? because im chaging that but im still getting the content from the H cell

Comment: @Miguel Thank you for replying. From your replying, I noticed that I misunderstood your goal. I apologize for this. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: No men you dont need to apologize, thanks for the support,I have made the change and its working fine.

Comment: @Miguel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your replying, I could notice that I overlooked it. Thank you, too.